# Github only host for static website and not able to modify the website after it online?

Tags: github, web, frontend, hosting

Did Github hosting a website as static website?
Is that mean I do not able to make any changes to the website?

Comment: You can host website through github with `branch` and if you make changes in the hosted branch then it will reflect in your website

Comment: Can you please specify your question? You can usually update the content of a page hosted with `GitHub Pages` by pushing to the designated branch. I would suggest you to have a look [`GitHub Pages` Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages) and especially the [Quickstart-Guide](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/quickstart)

Comment: My previous experience was reupload the modified files such as HTML and then published again, and it will failed everytime

Comment: "Static" doesn't mean you can't modify it. It just means modifications require redeploying your site. You can't do server-side logic or pull content in from a database, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand the difference between `GitHub` and `GitHub Pages`.

While using `GitHub`, you can store whatever you want (As long as it's legal). They are just files. You can delete, change and upload different files at any time.

While using `GitHub Pages`, the code stored on your GitHub repository will be available online. **You cannot create a backend to your website in GitHub pages, they are "static".** GitHub will just send the files you store in your repository to the people that visit the url, and the browser will display it as a website. **You can change the files in your repository,** and the website will be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes to your website in the repository which was hosted. When you first host a website using **github pages**, you'll create a **workflows** folder which **will re-deploy your website every time you commit** changes to your repository.